# Show inherit methods in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.0

How can i see an inherited methods at Android Studio?
Maybe, Android Studio has some shortcats for this?

I want to see all inherited methods of class and override it, if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ctrl + o` will give you all the methods that you can override in a class.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by this shortcut: "Alt+Insert" and pick "Overrides methods". You will see all overrides methods.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0gxm.png)